# Joined Object to Mesh Separates when Moved

Tags: mesh, armature, parent

So for this mesh, I decided to add a little rose to the shirt. The rose is made from grease pencil and turned into a mesh. So I joined the two objects first and then added an armature modifier and then parented with automatic weights to the armature. The rose will move with the shirt, but it won't move with the bones. I have tried weight painting the rose to a bone while connected to the shirt, but then it moves with the bone and changes places on the shirt. I have also tried parenting the rose to the shirt, but the bones still only move the shirt.

Here the rose and shirt are joined and moving as expected
[image]

Here it is still joined but does not move with the armature
[image]

Is there any way to get it to move with the shirt?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups*, remove the rose from all groups (down arrow dropdown menu > *Remove from All Groups*) then assign it to the vertex group you want.

Another way to fix this is to remove the rose vertices from all vertex groups, to separate it as a second object, then, in *Object* mode, select the rose, shift select the shirt, switch to *Edit* mode, select one or 3 vertices of the shirt and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Vertex Parent*, it will make the rose follow these vertices.